# WebApplicationInitializer called twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm creating a web-app with Spring MVC and ZK framework. I have a root project (jar) with all the base configuration of spring and zk, and a web-app project (war) calling the initializer.

This is my Initializer in my root project

```
public class DefaultInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private Class<?> config;

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        init();

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(config);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        container.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
        container.addListener(new HttpSessionListener());

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
                "mvc", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic zkDispatcher = container.addServlet(
                "zkLoader", new DHtmlLayoutServlet());
        zkDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        zkDispatcher.setInitParameter("update-uri", "/zkau");
        zkDispatcher.addMapping("*.zul");
        zkDispatcher.addMapping("*.zhtml");
        zkDispatcher.addMapping("/zk/*");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic zkUpdater = container.addServlet(
                "auEngine", new DHtmlUpdateServlet());
        zkUpdater.setLoadOnStartup(3);
        zkUpdater.addMapping("/zkau/*");

    }

    protected void setConfig(Class<?> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    protected void init() {
        setConfig(BaseConfig.class);
    }

}
```

So in my webapp project I only have to do

```
public class Initializer extends DefaultInitializer {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setConfig(WebConfig.class);
    }

}
```

where WebConfig is a ComponentScan and EnableWebMvc Java config.

The problem is when i start-up my Server with the web-app. The onStartup is called twice, and then it throws a NullPointerException.

I only have one web.xml and I only register one DispatcherServlet, and in my pom there is only one spring-web.jar being imported.

I'm using Spring 4, Java 1.8 and Tomcat v.8

Can someone give me a hint what is happening?

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the definition of the class **DefaultInitializer**.

DefaultInitializer should be **abstract**, so when Initializer extends DefaultInitializer only one instance is created implementing WebApplicationInitializer.